# How to recognize letters in curly style (eg, $\mathfrak{S}$, $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{I}$) for mathematical notations?

Tags: notation

Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic uses some notation in curly style, and I can't tell which letter is which. For example:

What is the letter ($\mathfrak{S}$) for sequent calculus?

[image]

and what are the letters ($\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$) and for an assignment and for an interpretation?

[image]

Is there a list of what all the letters in curly style are?

Thanks.

Comment: $\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

Comment: How did you type them?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Perhaps you should post this as a comment. I think it'd be a little more readable if you spaced out the letters as well though.

Comment: @tim The font is mathfrak

Comment: @Tim See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial. In this case, you want `\mathfrak`

Answer (score 5):

To get "Fraktur" (old German style) letters, type

`$\mathfrak{A\;B\; C\; D\; E\; F\; G\; H\; I\; J\; K\; L\; M\; N\; O\; P\; Q\; R\; S\; T\; U\; V\; W\; X\; Y\; Z}$`

to get
$\mathfrak{A\; B\; C\; D\; E\; F\; G\; H\; I\; J\; K\; L\; M\; N\; O\; P\; Q\; R\; S\; T\; U\; V\; W\; X\; Y\; Z }$.

The letters you asked about are  $\mathfrak S$   (S), $\mathfrak A$ (A), and $\mathfrak I$  (I).

Comment: I asked about three letters, and none of them looks like 

Comment: The one denoting a "calculus" in the first paragraph looks almost exactly like that!

Comment: @Tim: If you're seeing boxes instead of calligraphic letters, then your browser is having font-rendering issues. (It happens to me sometimes when people post formulas using Unicode characters instead of TeX markup. Come to think of it, it may have happened just now if your comment included a calligraphic character, since I see a box there. :) For an online reference, you can see Wikipedia's ["Fraktur"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) and ["Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols#Latin_letters) entries.